# Add character to trigger JTextPane line wrapping

Tags: java, character, jtextpane, word-wrap

I have a JTextPane that can display text containing nomenclature with long strings of characters, numbers and dashes ("-"). I have word wrapping turned on but, it appears to only work on white space (" ", tab, etc). I'd like to add the dash as a character that trippers line wrap. I tried adding a space or tab character after each dash to trigger the wrap but, this does not look good for the non-wrapped portions. Has anyone been able to trigger the line wrap in a JTextPane on any character that the default ones?

Comment: If you want people to provide good feedback, show them what you tried already. Right now, your question is quite vague.

Comment: I apologize, I thought I was clear that the only approach I found to trigger wrapping at a dash was to add white space characters after the dash but that did not look good for unwrapped strings. I have searched for several days for an approach that allows the code to add additional characters (cases?) to the wrapping algorithm so a dash can trigger the line wrap. Really don't have code samples as I have found no approach that allows this addition of other charaters.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a "hack solution" that works but, not one what I would prefer. I used replaceAll to add the "\r" character after each dash character. 
Caveat; I work in Java 7 under Windows 7 so this approach might not apply to other OS's or future Java versions. I can't really endorse this approach as a general solution to my question but it is working for me. The addition of "\r" does not show in the un-wrapped text but does trigger wrapping like other white space.
text.replaceAll("-","-\r");